# Proof of Monotone Class Theorem in L.F. Richardson's textbook

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading L.F. Richardson's textbook titled Measure and Integration. I am stuck in the proof of Monotone Class Theorem which the author states as follows:

> If $\mathfrak A$ is a field of subsets of $X$, then the monotone class
> $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ generated by $\mathfrak A$ equals the
> $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb B (\mathfrak A)$ generated by $\mathfrak A$.

To show that $\mathbb B (\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, the author wants to show that $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ is a field. He first proves that $\mathfrak B_A =\{B \subseteq X: A\cap B\in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)\}$ for any $A\in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ is a monotone class. Here's how he continues:

> Now that we know that $\mathfrak B_A$ is a monotone class, to complete
> the proof of $A\cap B\in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ whenever $A,B \in
>  \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, we need to prove that $\mathfrak B_A
>  \supseteq \mathfrak A$ so that we will know that $\mathfrak B _A
>  \supseteq \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$.
>
> (a) We start with a special case by *restricting* the set $A$ to be in
> $\mathfrak A$, fixed temporarily. That $\mathfrak B _A \supseteq
>  \mathfrak A$ follows in the special case from the fact that $\mathfrak
>  A$ is a field. Since we know already that $\mathfrak B_A$ is a
> monotone class, we have $\mathfrak B _A \supseteq \mathbb M (\mathfrak
>  A)$. Thus we have shown that $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ is closed under
> the operation on taking intersections with all $A\in \mathfrak A$.
>
> (b) For the full requirement, we relax the initial restriction and
> allow $A\in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ to be fixed arbitrarily. And now
> *we know from subcase (a)* that $\mathfrak B _A \supseteq \mathfrak A$. Since $\mathfrak B _A$ is a monotone class, it follows that $\mathfrak B _A
>  \supseteq \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, which is therefore closed under
> the operation of intersection.

I am unable to see why $\mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak B_A$ in subcase (b) of the author's proof. In subcase (a),  he proves that $\mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak B_A$ holds for $A\in \mathfrak A$. How does it extend to for any arbitrary $A\in  \mathbb M ( \mathfrak A )$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be clear what we want to prove.

We want to prove that $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ is closed under intersection, i.e.

$$ \forall A, B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), A \cap B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \cdots (*) $$

Define $ \mathfrak{B}_A =\{B \subseteq X: A\cap B\in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)\} $ as you said. Unraveling the definition, we can see that $(*)$ is exactly equivalent to

$$ \forall A \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), \mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A \cdots (**) $$

Next, let's break down the proof into three steps:

1. For any $A \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, $\mathfrak{B}_A$ is a monotone class
2. For any $A \in \mathfrak A$, we have $ \mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A $
3. For any $A \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, we have $ \mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A $

From step 1 and 3, we know that for each $A \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$, $\mathfrak{B}_A$ is a monotone class containing $\mathfrak A$, so it also contains the monotone class $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ generated by $\mathfrak A$. This is exactly what we want to prove in $(**)$.

You said you've already understood the proof of step 1 and 2. Your only problem is step 3, is this what you mean?

Suppose we've already proved step 1 and 2. Now **fix** $A \in \mathfrak A$. From step 2, we have $ \mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A $. But we already know $\mathfrak{B}_A$ is a monotone class from step 1! So $\mathfrak{B}_A$ must contain the monotone class $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ generated by $\mathfrak A$. The conclusion of this paragraph is this: **for any $A \in \mathfrak A$, $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A$**

What does that mean? Let's unravel the definition!

\begin{align*}
&\forall A \in \mathfrak A, \mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_A \\
\iff &\forall A \in \mathfrak A, \forall B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), B \in \mathfrak{B}_A \\
\iff &\forall A \in \mathfrak A, \forall B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), A \cap B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \\
\iff &\forall B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), \forall A \in \mathfrak A, B \cap A \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \\
\iff &\forall B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), \forall A \in \mathfrak A, A \in \mathfrak{B}_B \\
\iff &\forall B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A), \mathfrak A \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_B
\end{align*}

Now fix $B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$. The above means that $\mathfrak{B}_B$ is a monotone class containing $\mathfrak A$. Thus, $\mathbb M (\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathfrak{B}_B$. Finally, replace the dummy variable $B \in \mathbb M (\mathfrak A)$ by $A$ and we've proved step 3.